# How to send a text message from watch extension in apple watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Can we send a text message from watch extension by pre-populating the text and the contact number as I read [here](https://www.apple.com/watch/technology/) we can send by simply asking

> Siri to text a contact, and then start dictating.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you cant do it at the moment.

This message app you mentioned is a standard  Watch App, and we don't have access to it from WatchKit SDK.
Right now we don't have any access to  Watch hardware and apps.

In the iOS SDK it's possible to send SMS with [MessageUI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html),
or you can simple open SMS app
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:+1234567890"]];`

Maybe in future we will get some similar functionality.